# Reset random string for each instance with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm generating a random series of characters which will be added after a hidden character. I've also included the script used to hide the original message.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to "reset" the random string for each use. What's currently being returned is the same string for each instance. I'd like to insert a random string after each hidden character.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var message = "A random message with each character hidden in a span tag."

$(function() {  
  var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*()-_=+,./?";
  var string_length = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + 19;
  var randomstring = '';
  for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
    var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
    randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
  };

  $('body')
    .html(message)
    .children()
    .andSelf()
    .contents()
    .each(function(){
       var $this = $(this);
       $this.replaceWith($this.text().replace(/[A-Za-z0-9., ]/g, "<span hidden>$&</span>" + randomstring));
       console.log(randomstring);
       console.log(randomstring);
    });   
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making randomstring a function rather than just a variable.

```
var message = "A random message with each character hidden in a span tag."
function randomstring() {
  var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*()-_=+,./?";
  var string_length = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + 19;
  var result= '';
  for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
    var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
    result+= chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
  };
  return result;
}

$(function() {   
  $('body')
    .html(message)
    .children()
    .andSelf()
    .contents()
    .each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.replaceWith($this.text().replace(/[A-Za-z0-9., ]/g, "<span hidden>$&</span>" + randomstring()));
      console.log(randomstring());
      console.log(randomstring());
    });   
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Any idea how I could randomize each instance of randomstring() in the second function?

Comment: Everytime you call (use) randomstring() in your code you get a different string returned? Perhaps if you add some of the HTML that you are running this against it might help. Create a JSFiddle of your code to share.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z7T4F/ is a modified version. As you can see, the random string is repeating. I was wondering how to get a new string for each instance. Sorry but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Debugging your code, it would appear that randomstring is only called once, which is why it appears to be repeated. I am still not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve with this code. If you could be a bit more descriptive of what you are trying to achieve (I can sort of guess from the value of the message) but I am not sure how what you have so far comes close to achieving that. Perhaps try and modify your jQuery expression so that the randomstring is actually called multiple times, rather than a single time, that might get you on the path you're searching for.

Comment: I think I can see where your issue is. You want every replace that the regular expression does to call randomstring. This however is not the way it would work. It would call randonstring when it enters the function, and that string will be used for all of your replacements. You will have to re-engineer your code for the replacements, so that it loops through each character, then it will call randomstring each time and you will get a different string.

Answer (score 0):

You are only creating one randomstring and the code is done, then you start looping over elements and passing that same variable into the html.

You can remedy that with a simple function to get a new string on demand from within the `each` loop. I created a slightly more advanced function that will also make sure you have no repeats

```
var randString = (function() {
    var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*()-_=+,./?";    
    var strArray = this.strArray = [];/* store all strings created in array*/
    var createString = function () {
        var string_length = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + 19;
        var randomstring = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < string_length; i++) {
            var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
            randomstring += chars.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
        }
        return randomstring;
    }
     this.get= function () {
            var str = '';
            /* make sure output is unique*/
            while (strArray.indexOf(str) === -1) {
                str = createString();
                strArray.push(str);
           }            
            return str;
        }     
     return this;    
})();

$('body').html(message).children().andSelf().contents().each(function(){
    var randomstring = randString.get();
    /* your dom manipulation code */
});
```

Comment: This might be a bit too advanced for me to understand fully. I can't seem to find the proper dom manipulation code for output.

Comment: using the same output code doesn't return anything, nothing in body and no console errors